# Subgroups of $ \mathbb{R}^{*} $ and $ \mathbb{C}^{*} $ under multiplication

Tags: group-theory

I was studying subgroups then I asked myself what are the subgroups of  $ \mathbb{R}^{*} $ and  $ \mathbb{C}^{*} $ under multiplication

In my search i've found that $\alpha\mathbb{R}^{*} $ where  $\alpha$ is a real number different than zero but it was unconvincing and for  $ \mathbb{C}^{*} $ I've found only topics that treated finite subgroups.

Thanks, for reading my question.

Comment: Under multiplication or addition of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: it's under multiplication .

Comment: Then you may consider $\mathbb{R}^\times=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{C}^\times=\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$. Because $0$ is not invertible under multiplication

Comment: Sorry i missed that, thanks i will edit the question. Thanks

Comment: Well, for $\mathbb{R}^\times$, we see, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}^\times$, the cyclic subgroups $\{a^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, as well $\mathbb{Q}^\times$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, since $\exp:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^*$ is an injective group homomorphism, $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^*$, and all subgroups of this as well. And the subgroups of $(\mathbb{R},+)$ are up to isomorphism the torsion-free abelian groups of rank $\alpha$ for every cardinal $\alpha\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: and for $\mathbb{C} $ ?

Comment: Have look at this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2323300/are-proper-subgroups-of-bbb-c-cyclic). Note that $\mathbb{C}^*=\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.