# Numbers of subgroups which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, direct-sum

> **Question**: if $G=\mathbb{Z_2}\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}\oplus...\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}$($n$ copies where $n≥3$) then number of subgroups of $G$ which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}$ is ?

**My attempt:** when $G=\mathbb{Z_2}\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}$ I saw there are $7$ distinct subgroups which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_2}\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}$. But for this, I calculated each of them by hand.They are $<(0,0,1),(0,1,0)>, <(0,0,1),(1,0,0)>, <(0,0,1),(1,1,0)>, <(0,1,0),(1,0,0)>, <(0,1,0),(1,1,1)>, <(1,1,0),(0,1,1)>, <(1,1,1),(0,1,1)>$  where $<a,b>$ means subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$.

**Now  when $n≥4$ how to find number of such subgroups? and which are they?**  Please help

Comment: To avoid a wrong impression: I didn't answer because of but rather despite the request "Please help" in boldface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any two distinct non-zero elements of $G$ generate a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2$. Each such subgroup is generated by any pair of its non-zero elements. Thus there are

$$
\frac{\binom{2^n-1}2}{\binom32}=\frac{\left(2^n-1\right)\left(2^n-2\right)}6
$$

such subgroups.

Comment: Sir is there is any proof to your formula. Please elaborate

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: Sure, the proof is in the sentence above. There are $\binom{2^n-1}2$ different pairs that generate these subgroups, and each subgroup is generated by $\binom32$ pairs; hence there are $\frac{\binom{2^n-1}2}{\binom32}$ subgroups.

Comment: sir. One more thing I like to ask  each subgroup is generated by $\binom32$ pairs? Didn't get it

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: Each subgroup has $2\cdot2=4$ elements, of which $3$ are non-zero. There are $\binom32$ ways to choose pairs from $3$ elements.