# Is there a group with countably many subgroups, but is not countable in ZF?

Tags: group-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527318/countable-number-of-subgroups-implies-countable-group), although I don't think it was the OP's intention, hence this separate question: Is there a group $G$ with countably many subgroups, but is a not a countable group itself in $\mathrm{ZF}$?

In $\mathrm{ZFC}$ we can look at the cyclic subgroups of $G$ and "estimate" the number of elements in the group, to conclude that $G$ is countable. But this ends up not going through in $\mathrm{ZF}$ since a countable union of finite sets does not have to be countable, in particular it is known that a countable union of two-element sets does not have to be countable.

So a possible way to construct such a uncountable group (although I am not saying this is a good way to go, I have no idea) is start with a collection $\{ A_i \mid i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ where $A_i$ are pairs, whose union is not a countable set and note that every torsion-free cyclic group has two natural generators, so conceivably there could be a torsion-free group with $A_i$ the natural generating set for a cyclic groups ("$1,-1$" but we could not actually define such a function all $A_i$ without the axiom of choice). Then the constructions would have to make sure there are only countable many subgroups (this seems difficult and would take a lot of care)

An interesting [paper](http://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/119630) "On the number of Russell's socks or $2+2+2+\cdots = ?$" 
by Horst Herrlich, Eleftherios Tachtsis discusses some of the ideas around countable unions of pairs.

Comment: A countable union of finite sets is countable.  In fact, a countable union of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126: only with the axiom of choice.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 In ZFC that is true, but you can not arrive to that conclusion in ZF, as I said in the post.

Comment: Sorry about that.  My brain added a "C" at the end of "ZF".

Comment: With the axiom of choice, the easiest proof (that I know) shows that an uncountable group has uncountably many *cyclic* subgroups. So a related question, that also seems interesting, but might be easier to think about, is whether, without the axiom of choice, an uncountable group must have uncountably many *cyclic* subgroups.

Comment: If you had the described injection $S_{\mathbb N}\hookrightarrow S_A$, wouldn't that give you a sock-choosing function? Choose an element of $A_0$; this entails a choice of an element of each $A_i$ by considering the image of the permutation that swaps $0$ with $i$.

Comment: And there certainly is an injection $f:X\hookrightarrow S_X$ for every set $X$, without choice: If $X$ is empty then this is trivial; otherwise choose a fixed $x_0\in X$ and let $f(x)$ be the transposition $(x\;x_0)$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah yes, you are right on all counts. I seemed to have missed that you would have to define these permutations on the elements, and just thought of pairs when I was writing this. (I removed the material from the post)

Comment: @PaulPlummer Does my answer seem to work? (Looking at it now, I believe it does.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I apologizes for taking so long, I was meaning to crack open Jech to check/learn the details (my set theory knowledge falls short of most of the answer making complete sense), but it doesn't look like that will be happening anytime soon... The group theory seems to work, and I assume you know what you are doing set theory wise, seems like a fairly standard way to get these sort of choice defying results. I will accept it. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @darij: I admit that I find your edit comment a bit confusing.

Comment: I was just quipping at an alternative (mis)interpretation of the unhyphenated "two element".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes, as follows:

Start with a model of ZF+atoms, $M$, with a set of atoms $A$ which forms a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{D}/\mathbb{Z}$, where $\mathbb{D}$ is the set of *dyadic fractions*: $\mathbb{D}=\{{p\over 2^k}: p, k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Let $G$ be the group of automorphisms of $A$, and consider the symmetric submodel $N$ of $M$ corresponding to the filter of finite supports on $G$. Then in $N$, $A$ is no longer countable, since there are nontrivial automorphisms of $\mathbb{D}/\mathbb{Z}$ fixing arbitrary finite sets; but the only subgroups of $\mathbb{D}/\mathbb{Z}$, other than the whole thing, are those of the form $$\{x: 2^kx=0\}$$ for some fixed $k\in\mathbb{N}$. This provides an explicit bijection - in the original universe, $M$ - between the subgroups of $A$ and $\omega$. Now, passing to $N$, we get no *additional* subgroups of $A$, and the map described above is symmetric; so in $N$, $A$ has only countably many subgroups.

Meanwhile, the statements "$A$ is uncountable" and "$A$ has countably many finitely generated subgroups" are each "bounded," so we may apply the Jech-Sochor theorem to push this construction into the ZF-setting.

Comment: The set of atoms is also "nicely definable", but it's not countable anymore, and certainly the set of Its finite subsets if not countable. You need to argue better why the collection of subgroups is countable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila My thoughts got garbled when I was writing this - this is just for the simpler question of getting countably many *finitely generated* subgroups. For $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, every finitely generated subgroup is definable in an explicit way as the set of elements with order (dividing) a fixed number, and this provides a perfectly symmetric bijection from $\{$finitely generated subgroups$\}$ to $\omega$.

Comment: This example **does**, unfortunately, have uncountably many subgroups: for every set of primes $X$ we can associate the least subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ containing every element of order $\in X$.

Comment: Hmm, yes. I agree with that first comment; with the second also, and this is where my concern lies in the possibility of this even happening. I think the right theorem would be from ZF that a group with only countably many subgroups is finitely generated.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hang on, what about the group $B$ of dyadic rationals mod $\mathbb{Z}$? A symmetric copy of this would again have countably many finitely generated subgroups, while being uncountable - and unless I'm having a silly moment, $B$ has **only** finitely-generated subgroups (other than $B$ itself), so this would work.

Comment: Well, let's put it in easy model theoretic notions. If you can find a group which is "sufficiently homogeneous" and only definable proper subgroups are finite, and there are countably many of them; if you can find such object, then it's easy to construct a generic copy of that group which only has countably many subgroups.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I'm aware - but what do you think of the specific example I gave in my previous comment? As far as I can tell, it seems to answer the question. I have edited my answer, let me know what you think.

Comment: Unfortunately my group theoretic intuition is not at the point where I can immediately give you an answer, and my schedule for the day which has just begun is entirely full with other things. It does sound like a reasonable route to explore, though, with that I agree.