# Can an uncountable group have a countable number of subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, infinite-groups

> Can an uncountable group have only a countable number of subgroups?
>
> Please give examples if any exist!

Edit: I want a group having uncountable cardinality but having a countable number of subgroups.

By countable number of subgroups, I mean the collection of all subgroups of a group is countable.

Comment: I'm frankly a bit surprised at the negative reaction to this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Countable number of subgroups $\implies $ countable group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527318/countable-number-of-subgroups-implies-countable-group)

Comment: Then why is it marked as "off-topic" rather than "duplicate"?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen.  If it should be closed please give the correct reason.

Comment: @CMonsour It was closed because there is no context. It's just a problem statement with no details. The closure reason is correct. While it might be better that it be listed as a duplicate, I don't see that as a reason to reopen.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No. Suppose $G$ is an uncountable group. Every element $g$ of $G$ belongs to a countable subgroup of $G$, namely the cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle$. Thus $G$ is the union of all of its countable subgroups. Since a countable union of countable sets is countable, $G$ must have uncountably many countable subgroups.

Comment: How can we be sure that the subgroups generated by $g$ and $g'$ (for $g\not= g'$) are not the same?

Comment: With a bit of refinement, this argument can be turned into the group being a countable union of finite sets. I forgot if this makes it countable without choice.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The axiom of choice is needed to prove that a countable union of two-element sets is countable. (If the union were countable, you could prove the axiom of choice for two-element sets.)

Comment: @BenjaminH : You can't, for a specific pair $g,g'$. However, both $\langle g\rangle$ and $\langle g'\rangle$ are countable, so there are indeed uncountably many such subgroups (otherwise a countable union of countable sets would exhaust $G$, which is not possible).

Answer (score 11):

*EDIT: bof's answer is the right one, but the construction below - while completely pointless overkill - is still an example of a useful technique, so I'm leaving this answer up.*

---

No, this cannot happen.

Suppose $G$ is a group and $A$ is a countable subset of $G$. Then the closure of $A$ under the group operations ($*$ and $^{-1}$) of $G$, $\langle A\rangle$, *is again countable* - this is a good exercise (HINT: the set of finite strings from a countable set is countable).

With this in hand, if $G$ is an uncountable group we can build an uncountable chain of subgroups of $G$, as follows:

- We will define a countable subgroup $A_\delta$ for every countable ordinal $\delta$. There are uncountably many of these, so if we can do this we'll be done.
- We let $A_0$ be the trivial subgroup.
- Having defined $A_\eta$ for every $\eta<\delta$, we let $a$ be some element of $G$ not in $\bigcup_{\eta<\delta}A_\eta$ - which exists, since this is a countable union of countable subgroups, and $G$ is uncountable - and let $A_\delta=\langle (\bigcup_{\eta<\delta}A_\eta)\cup\{a\}\rangle$.
- It's easy to prove by transfinite induction that $(A_\delta)_{\delta<\omega_1}$ is a strictly increasing chain of countable subgroups of $G$, so we're done.

Comment: Both answers use the axiom of choice. In ZF, can there be an uncountable group with only a countable number of subgroups?

Comment: @bof [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532136/is-there-a-group-with-countably-many-subgroups-but-is-not-countable-in-zf) that I asked and Noah answered a while ago should answer your question