# Countable abelian Group Vs Non-Abelian countable Group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Countable  abelian Group Vs  Non-Abelian countable  Group

which of the  following statement is True/false ?

$1$. Countable  abelian group can have only countably many  distinct  subgroup

$2.$ Countable Non-abelian group  can have only  countably  many distinct subgroup

My Try : For  $1.$  i got false by [countable group, uncountably many distinct subgroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257175/countable-group-uncountably-many-distinct-subgroup)

Im confused  about  $2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a countable abelian group with uncountably many subgroups.
Then $G\times S_3$ is a countable non-abelian group with uncountably many subgroups (even with uncountably many of the form $H\times S_3$, i.e., also non-abelian).